# Scalatags conditional attribute

Tags: scala, attributes, conditional-statements, scalatags

I'm trying to write a wrapper around the `select` element. So in principle I want to be able to specify that given some boolean `multiple` I want to append the `multiple` attribute or not. Below I've given a small example:

```
select (id := someId, name := someName, if (multiple) "multiple".attr := "")
```

This obviously won't compile, but it should convey my intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
val attrList = if (multiple) List("multiple".attr = "") else List.empty
select (id := someId, name := someName)(attrList:_*)
```

This way its conditional whether you add that attribute or not.

Comment: It's close to what I eventually did. I've chosen to use an `Option` rather than a `List`. While reading the code, this makes a bit more sense to me. `val multipleAttr = if (multiple) Some("multiple".attr := "") else None` And the I use it as: `select(id := someId, name := someName, multipleAttr)`. This works as well. I accepted the answer because it works as well.